# How to mklink /home/ to a new empty partition

Tags: lubuntu, swap, symbolic-link

Due some weird issues with my current lubuntu I'm going to do fresh installation. But when I install lubuntu I need to do two things that I probably can't perform because I'm newbie.

I'm going to create 30GB of unallocated space on my SSD. I want to install lubuntu there and I want to create 20GB swap file. Can you please tell me how to do it?
Another thing: When I will install Lubuntu I need to do mkling (symlink) hard symlink. I need to move entire /home/ folder from SSD to HDD partition. I don't want temporally link. I want to do move /home/ forever.
Please explain me how to create 20GB page file when I install lubuntu and please send me commands and steps that allow me to do /home/ mklink

Comment: you don't need to use symlinks, you can just mount /home from a different partition. There are many answers about this already: http://askubuntu.com/search?q=move+%2Fhome+partition

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this all graphically on the lubuntu installer. Just select you want to manually set up the partitions. This beings up a graphical interface. You can tell it where to format and put your operating system. You can shrink partitions, make new ones (one you need to format as a swap-parition). And there is also a mount point option. You mount your home drive/partition at `/home`

Answer (score 0):

Also, If you want to copy an entire partition from the "SSD" to a new hard drive "HDD"

[(look here for how rsync is used to copy over an entire partition.)](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving)